# Making font weight bold by passing value in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I want to change a font weight from normal to bold by clicking checkbox input.

I tried to apply a ternary operator but it didn't work.

```
bold={ this.state.checkboxState ? this.props.bold : !this.props.bold }
```

What is the best way to implement this functionality?

Here is a [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/aaayumi/pen/zERPbo/).

The code

```
class FontChooser extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            hidden: true,
            checkboxState : true
        }
    }
    toggle(e) {
        this.setState({
            checkboxState : !this.state.checkboxState
        })
        console.log(!this.state.isChecked)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" 
                    id="boldCheckbox"
                    checked={this.state.isChecked}
                    onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}
                />
               <span 
                   id="textSpan" 
                   bold={ this.state.checkboxState ? this.props.bold : !this.props.bold }
               >
                   {this.props.text}
               </span>
           </div>
       );
    }
}

React.render(
    <div>
        <FontChooser text='Fun with React!' bold='false' />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Thank you for your kind advice.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Change `<span id="textSpan">` to the following:

```
<span 
    id="textSpan" 
    style={ this.state.checkboxState ? { fontWeight: 'normal' } : { fontWeight: 'bold' } }
>
    { this.props.text }
</span>
```

Comment: thanks. I came up with this solution as well. What I wanted to know is to use 'bold' and boolean. I want to change ` bold='false`.

Comment: So, in your input, you set the checked value to be `this.state.isChecked` but you never change this value. Did you mean to use `this.state.checkboxState`? Second, when you set the value of the bold property on the `FontChooser` element in `React.render`, change it from `bold='false'` to `bold={false}`. This way the value is passed as a boolean and you can change it's value easily with the ternary statement you already are using.

Comment: Good answer! Slightly tidier: `style={{ fontWeight: this.state.checkboxState ? 'normal':'bold' }}`

Answer (score 0):

Use **fontWidth** in element inline or css identifier.

```
<i className={ `fa fa-${ notif.icon }` } style={{color:`${notif.color}`, fontSize: '15px', marginRight: '0.5rem', fontWeight: 'bold'}}></i>
```